# Can this Query be simplified

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**EDIT**

Here is an example of my data:

```
 create TABLE #Table 
(
    [Market] VARCHAR(100),
    [Operator] VARCHAR(100),
    [Date] DATE,
    [Num Registrations] INT,
    [Num Active] INT,
    [Num Accepted Purchases] INT
)

INSERT INTO #Table VALUES
('Market1','Operator1','2012-12-01',2,4,7),
('Market1','Operator2','2012-12-01',3,5,7),
('Market1','Operator3','2012-12-01',1,2,7),
('Market2','Operator4','2012-12-01',2,1,7),
('Market2','Operator5','2012-12-01',0,4,7),
('Market3','Operator6','2012-12-01',2,44,7)
```

I have the following script:

```
SELECT 
    a.[Market],
    a.[Operator],
    a.[Date],
    a.[Num Registrations],
    a.[Num Active],
    a.[Num Accepted Purchases],
    [rnk] = b.rnk
FROM 
    #Table a
    INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT 
            [Market],
            [rnk] = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM([Num Registrations] + [Num Active]))
        FROM #Table
        GROUP BY [Market]
        ) b
        ON 
          a.[Market] = b.[Market]
GROUP BY
    a.[Market],
    a.[Operator],
    a.[Date],
    a.[Num Registrations],
    a.[Num Active],
    a.[Num Accepted Purchases],
    b.rnk
```

The above works ok but have I over-complicated things with the `sub-query`; could I have used the `RANK` function directly in the main query's `SELECT` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't need to do an explicit join at all:

```
SELECT distinct
    a.[Market],
    a.[Operator],
    a.[Date],
    a.[Num Registrations],
    a.[Num Active],
    a.[Num Accepted Purchases],
    [rnk] = dense_rank() over (order by tot, market)
FROM (select a.*,
             sum(a.[Num Registrations] + a.[Num Active]) over (partition by market) as tot
      from xxx.dbo.tb_r12044dxx_yyyy a
     ) a
```

If you don't have duplicates, then you can remove the `distinct` from the `select`.

Comment: No gordon ....that gives me the rank of each operator within each market. So say there are 5 markets and 100 operators in each. Your query gives 1-100 five times. All I want in the column [rnk] is the rank of the 5 markets i.e. 1-5, so effectively the field will contain 1 repeated 100 times and then 2 repeated 100 times ...

Comment: @whytheq . . . I see that.  You can still get rid of the separate join.  The modified query calculates the total across markets and then uses `dense_rank` to apply the ranking to each market.

Answer (score 1):

I think the final group by is redundant, but I can't see a way to avoid the sub query..

I'm not sure whether the following is any more efficient, you'd have to try it with your data, but its debatably easier to read:

```
SELECT 
    a.[Market],
    a.[Operator],
    a.[Date],
    a.[Num Registrations],
    a.[Num Active],
    a.[Num Accepted Purchases],
    [rnk] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY NumToRankOver)
FROM xxx.dbo.tb_r12044dxx_yyyy a
INNER 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    [Market],
    SUM([Num Registrations] + [Num Active]) AS NumToRankOver
    FROM xxx.dbo.tb_r12044dxx_yyyy
    GROUP BY [Market]
) b
    ON  a.[Market] = b.[Market]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it looks like with a cte.

```
 DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    [Market] VARCHAR(100),
    [Operator] VARCHAR(100),
    [Date] DATE,
    [Num Registrations] INT,
    [Num Active] INT,
    [Num Accepted Purchases] INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('Market1','Operator1','2012-12-01',2,4,7),
('Market2','Operator2','2012-12-01',3,5,7),
('Market3','Operator3','2012-12-01',1,2,7),
('Market4','Operator4','2012-12-01',2,1,7),
('Market5','Operator5','2012-12-01',0,4,7),
('Market6','Operator6','2012-12-01',2,44,7)

--with cte
    ;WITH Cte_Rank AS
    (
        SELECT 
             a.[Market],
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(a.[Num Registrations] + a.[Num Active])) [Rnk]
        FROM @Table a GROUP BY a.Market 
    )
    SELECT 
        a.[Market],
        a.[Operator],
        a.[Date],
        a.[Num Registrations],
        a.[Num Active],
        a.[Num Accepted Purchases],
        c.Rnk
    FROM @Table a
    INNER JOIN Cte_Rank c ON c.Market = a.Market


--The only way to avoid subquery is to get rid of the "SUM" aggregate       
    SELECT 
        a.[Market],
        a.[Operator],
        a.[Date],
        a.[Num Registrations],
        a.[Num Active],
        a.[Num Accepted Purchases],
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.[Num Registrations] + a.[Num Active]) [Rnk]
    FROM @Table a
```

Comment: +1 yep - I'm familiar with `CTE` and use them pretty regularly - I think this looks cleaner than my code and slightly more readable.

Comment: why are you using TVPs ?! ...why not just # tables? You have misinterpretted the initial table. Let me add a `CREATE TABLE` script to the OP. What it means is that your two solutions are returning different results.

Comment: The above is just an example using a table variable, you can use the table type that suites you best (eg Temp table). The second query is just to show you how it would look like without the SUM aggregate, in that case the subquery could be removed, but obviously the results would be different. These are just illustrations and guidelines.